# Which solver solves PSD constrained convex non-linear problem

Tags: optimization, solver, convex-optimization, sdp, mosek

I have a problem with a vector variable $w \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and a symmetric matrix variable $V \in \mathbb{R^{n \times n}}$. I am solving a problem which is roughly like:

\begin{align}
\begin{array}{ll}
\max & \sqrt{\operatorname{trace}(A^\top V A)} + a^\top w + \operatorname{entropy}(w) \\
\mathrm{s.t. }& \text{some linear constraints over $w$, and $V$}\\
&  V \succeq ww^\top
\end{array}
\end{align}
where by Schur complement the last constraint can be:
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
V & w \\ w^\top & 1
\end{pmatrix} \succeq 0.
\end{align}

So, I have a positive semi-definiteness constraint, some linear constraints, and the function that I am maximizing is concave because the square root of a linear function is concave, as well as the entropy.

I am using YALMIP - MATLAB combination to call a solver. However, MOSEK cannot solve this. I know MOSEK can solve entropy maximization over some conic constraints (exponential cone solver), but this problem is not being able to solve.

Am I using MOSEK wrongly? Would you expect MOSEK to solve this problem? If not, which convex optimization solver shall I try using?

Comment: As discussed below, this is solvable using YALMIP  + Mosek now with the bug fix in the latest develop branch.  Also make sure to use convexity aware operator sqrtm and not general nonlinear function sqrt.

Comment: @JohanLöfberg Shall I check here for the difference between sqrt and sqrtm: https://yalmip.github.io/squareroots/ 

The thing is, trace is scalar so I don't get  why it is beneficial to use sqrtm.

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with scalar vs matrix in YALMIP. sqrtm is convexity aware and modelled by SOCP cones, sqrt is a callback based.

Comment: ...and I got it backwards. sqrt is the operator to use, sqrtm is the general nonlinear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT:** Per comment below by YALMIP deveeloper Johan Lofberg, the bug in YALMIP was a typo, which has now been corrected and available at https://github.com/yalmip/YALMIP/archive/develop.zip .  Using this newest develop version of YALMIP, Mosek should now be able to solve the problem.

Edited to reflect YALMIP developer's acknowledgement that there is a bug in YALMIP.

Mosek should be able to solve this, and indeed can (see below) under CVX 2.2.

There is a bug in YALMIP which results in an error message when entropy is used in combination with an SDP constraint with the solvers Mosek or SCS.

For example,

```
X=sdpvar(3,3);optimize(X>=0,-entropy(X(:)),sdpsettings('solver','mosek','debug',1))

Unrecognized function or variable 'sdpDAta'.
Error in normalizeExponentialCone (line 236)
            sdpDAta(end,size(model.F_struc,2)) = 0;
Error in callmosek>call_mosek_lpqpsocpsdp (line 84)
[model,output] = normalizeExponentialCone(model);
Error in callmosek (line 51)
    [x,D_struc,problem,r,res,solvertime,prob] = call_mosek_lpqpsocpsdp(model);
Error in solvesdp (line 361)
    eval(['output = ' solver.call '(interfacedata);']);
Error in optimize (line 31)
[varargout{1:nargout}] = solvesdp(varargin{:});
```

Similarly with SCS as solver (which absent the YALMIP bug, also should be able to solve this).

See the YALMIP forum topic [Entropy + SDP constraint with Mosek and SCS: Unrecognized function or variable 'sdpDAta'](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/yalmip/O0Qc78d9ORs) which I just opened, to which the YALMIP developer, Johan Lofberg, has now responded, acknowledging the bug.

CVX 2.2 + Mosek 9.1 as solver can handle this.

```
cvx_begin sdp
variable V(3,3) symmetric
variable w(3)
maximize(sqrt(A'*V*A)+a'*w+sum(entr(w)))
% Insert other constraints here
[V w;w' 1] >= 0
cvx_solver mosek
cvx_end
```

Comment: Johan replied to my YALMIP forum topic, acknowledging that is is a bug.  Anyhow, as I mentioned in the answer. CVX 2.2 + Mosek as solver can handle this, using syntax not all that different than YALMIP.

Comment: It's been fixed in the develop branch now (typo in code, simply change sdpDAta to sdpData on the line that crashes in matlab...)

Comment: @Johan Löfberg Thanks. I guess you held the shift key for a fraction of a second longer than you should have during coding.

Comment: Yes, and obviously I am missing a test in my test suite.

Comment: This is a great answer, thanks Mark! @JohanLöfberg thanks for updating YALMIP!

Comment: For bigger instances there is a very good chance that the dual problem will solve faster.